# Youtube API OAuth 2.0 on UWP error 400

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, uwp, win-universal-app, youtube-data-api

when i send a Post request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` get an error 400

This is my code

```
private async Task<string> PostAsync(string requestUriString, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> content)
{
    string contentString = "";
    content.ForEach(kvp => contentString += WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key) + "=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value) + "&");
    contentString = contentString.Remove(contentString.Length - 1);

    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUriString) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    TaskFactory taskFactory = new TaskFactory();
    Task<Stream> requestTask = taskFactory.FromAsync(webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream, webRequest.EndGetRequestStream, null);
    using (Stream requestStream = await requestTask)
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
        {
            streamWriter.Write(contentString);
            streamWriter.Dispose();
        }
        requestStream.Dispose();
    }

    string responseString = null;
    Task<WebResponse> responseTask = taskFactory.FromAsync(webRequest.BeginGetResponse, webRequest.EndGetResponse, null);
    WebResponse webResponse = await responseTask;
    using (Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            streamReader.Dispose();
        }
        responseStream.Dispose();
    }
    return responseString;
}

private async void WebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    if (webView.DocumentTitle.StartsWith("Success code="))
    {
        string autorizationCode = webView.DocumentTitle.Substring(13);
        string responseString = await PostAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?",
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code",autorizationCode),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret","xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri","http://localhost/oauth2callback"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","authorization_code")
            }
        );
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(responseString);
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using YouTube Data API in an UWP app, then the OAuth 2.0 flow will like the [installed application flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps) that supports applications installed on a device, such as a phone or computer.

To get the access token, we can follow the steps in [Obtaining OAuth 2.0 access tokens](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#Obtaining_Access_Tokens). And in UWP, we can use [`WebAuthenticationBroker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx) class to start the authentication operation.

> The Web Authentication Broker allows applications to use internet authentication and authorization protocols like OpenID or OAuth to connect to online identity providers. An app can choose to use the web authentication broker to sign in to OAuth or OpenID protocol-based web services, such as many social network and picture-sharing websites, provided that the particular service provider has made the necessary changes.

For more information, please see [Web authentication broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt270196.aspx).

Following is a sample about how to obtain the access token with [`WebAuthenticationBroker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx) class and [`Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) class:

```
String YouTubeURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(ClientID) + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob") + "&response_type=code&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

Uri StartUri = new Uri(YouTubeURL);
// As I use "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" as the redirect_uri, the success code is displayed in the html title of following end uri
Uri EndUri = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?");

WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle, StartUri, EndUri);
if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
{
    var autorizationCode = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.Substring(13);
    var pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    pairs.Add("code", autorizationCode);
    pairs.Add("client_id", ClientID);
    pairs.Add("client_secret", ClientSecret);
    pairs.Add("redirect_uri", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
    pairs.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");

    var formContent = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"), formContent);
    string response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

And the `response` is like:

[image]